# psql: CASE usage

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, psql

I am learning psql, and pretty confused with the CASE keyword.

Say I have a table "pets".

```
    name     | species |       owner        | gender |     color
-------------+---------+--------------------+--------+---------------
 Nagini      | snake   | Lord Voldemort     | female | green
 Hedwig      | owl     | Harry Potter       | female | snow white
 Scabbers    | rat     | Ron Weasley        | male   | unspecified
 Pigwidgeon  | owl     | Ron Weasley        | male   | grey
 Crookshanks | cat     | Herminone Granger  | male   | ginger
 Mrs Norris  | cat     | Argus Filch        | female | dust-coloured
 Trevor      | toad    | Neville Longbottom | male   | brown
```

I am asked to 
"Use CASE to show pet names and a column to indicate whether the pet's name is long or short (a long name is strictly more than 6 characters long). Filter to select only female pets."

The official document only gives examples using CASE solely on its own. When I try to solve the problem, I tried

```
SELECT * 
CASE 
  WHEN name > 6 THEN
    msg:= 'long'
  ELSE 
    msg:= 'short'
END CASE
FROM pets WHERE gender = 'female';
```

which gave me an error `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CASE"`

Can I combine the CASE with SELECT statement? If yes how? If no, how could I solve above task?

Comment: Did you see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-conditional.htm? You need a case expression rather than a case statement for your case, which will give you another result column. And adding the column after * without a comma to separate it won't work either even if it wasn't a case expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per PostgreSQL documentation (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html), the proper way to a case expression is:

`CASE WHEN condition THEN result
     [WHEN ...]
     [ELSE result]
END`

According to the code you posted, you are ending the expression with END CASE when it should be END. Also you forgot to add a comma after the asterix. I would write your query in the following way:

`SELECT *, 
CASE 
  WHEN length(name) > 6 THEN 'long'
  ELSE 'short'
END as msg
FROM pets WHERE gender = 'female';`

Comment: Should be `length(name) > 6`

Comment: Indeed length(name) > 6 is needed, but this works! In what situations do I need the comma after the asterisk?

Comment: @Meruemu, you will need a comma in order to separate columns. Asterisk will give you all the columns from the original table then you need the comma to add the new column you wanted.